# (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) No view model association found for candidate view RootActivity

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm having a problem with binding in MvvmCross and Xamarin Forms. When I'm navigating from my MainViewModel to FileInfoViewModel, I'm getting following error:

(MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) No view model association found for candidate view RootActivity

I have used MvvmCross setup like described [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/05/08/build-a-xamarin.forms-application.aspx)

This is my RootActivity.cs code in Android project:

```
    [Activity(Label = "XFCubage", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class RootActivity : MvxFormsAppCompatActivity<MvxFormsAndroidSetup<Core.App, App>, Core.App, App>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

This is my FileInfoViewModel.cs that I'm navigating from MainViewModel (during navigation, I'm passing object InfoDetail):

```
namespace XFCubage.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class FileInfoViewModel : MvxViewModel<InfoDetail>
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SideMenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
        public InfoDetail Detail { get; private set; }
        public SideMenuItem SelectedMenuItem { get; set; }
        private int _sideMenuWidth;
        public int SideMenuWidth
        {
            get => _sideMenuWidth;
            set => SetProperty(ref _sideMenuWidth, value);
        }

        private IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

        public FileInfoViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;

            InitializeSideMenuItems();

            CrossDeviceOrientation.Current.OrientationChanged += (sender, 
            args) =>
            {
                var orientation = args.Orientation;
                SetSideMenuWidth(orientation);
            };
        }


        void SetSideMenuWidth(DeviceOrientations orientation)
        {
            if (orientation == DeviceOrientations.Landscape || 
                orientation == DeviceOrientations.LandscapeFlipped)
                SideMenuWidth = 250;
            else
                SideMenuWidth = 65;
        }

        public void InitializeSideMenuItems()
        {
            MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<SideMenuItem>();
            MenuItems.Add(new SideMenuItem() { Id = 1, Title = "FILE INFO", ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("fileinfo.png"), Selected = true });
            MenuItems.Add(new SideMenuItem() { Id = 2, Title = "LOADING ADDRESS", ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("loadingaddress.png"), Selected = false });
            MenuItems.Add(new SideMenuItem() { Id = 3, Title = "DELIVERY ADDRESS", ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("deliveryaddress.png"), Selected = false });
            MenuItems.Add(new SideMenuItem() { Id = 4, Title = "QUOTE ADDRESS", ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("quoteaddress.png"), Selected = false });
            MenuItems.Add(new SideMenuItem() { Id = 5, Title = "BILLING ADDRESS", ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("wallet.png"), Selected = false });
            MenuItems.Add(new SideMenuItem() { Id = 6, Title = "ROOMS", ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("rooms.png"), Selected = false });
            MenuItems.Add(new SideMenuItem() { Id = 7, Title = "SUMMARY", ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("summary.png"), Selected = false });
            SelectedMenuItem = MenuItems[0];
        }

        public override void Prepare(InfoDetail parameter)
        {
            Detail = parameter;
        }
    }
}
```

This my FileInfoPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:MvxContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    xmlns:components="clr-namespace:XFCubage.Core.Components;assembly=XFCubage.Core"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:XFCubage.Core.ViewModels;assembly=XFCubage.Core"
    x:TypeArguments="viewModels:FileInfoViewModel"
    x:Class="XFCubage.Views.FileInfoPage"
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PageBackgroundColor}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding SideMenuWidth}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <listview:SfListView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" 
                         BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TableHeaderBackground}" 
                         ItemSpacing="0,10,0,10" 
                         SelectionMode="Single" SelectionGesture="Tap" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <listview:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <BoxView WidthRequest="3"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" WidthRequest="24" HeightRequest="24" Margin="10,0,20,0"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </listview:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
        <listview:SfListView.SelectedItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource SelectedItemBackgroundColor}">
                    <BoxView WidthRequest="3" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HighlightColor}"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" WidthRequest="24" HeightRequest="24" Margin="10,0,20,0"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </listview:SfListView.SelectedItemTemplate>
    </listview:SfListView>
</Grid>
```

Problem occures in this line in XAML bindin. I receive an error:

**(MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) No view model association found for candidate view RootActivity**:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding SideMenuWidth}"/>
```

When I change this line to:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
```

Everything seems to be okay. The stranges thing is that binding for listview  (model **Detail** that I'm passing from MainViewModel to FileInfoViewModel) works.

Can you please help me because I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I don’t see where you are linking the (data) ViewModel to (UI)FileInfoPagelian, I guess it is the reason you have this error message.

Usually, I create Xamarin.Form, the UI is in xxx.xaml, connecting Viewmodel in xxx.xaml.cs, like this:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-create-mvvm-data-binding-application/

Comment: With MvvmCross in xaml you put:         x:TypeArguments="viewModels:FileInfoViewModel"